# Sketching an elliptic paraboloid

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

I am struggling a bit here, mainly because graphing has never been my strong suit and I have some how made it to multivariable calculus.

I have an elliptic paraboloid it's equation is:
$$4(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2 = \frac{x}{4}$$

From what I've seen your suppose to find the traces which you do by first setting one of the variables = to 0 this, tells you what the 2d shape is then you change the variable to some constant k.

So then

yz plane: $(y-2)^2+\frac{(z-2)^2}{4}=k$

yx plane: $(y-2)^2=\frac{x}{4}$ A parabola, $(y-2)^2+\frac{k^2}{4}=x$

zx plane: $\frac{(z-2)^2}{4}=\frac{x}{4}$, parabola, $(z-2)^2 + \frac{k^2}{4}=x$

Those are the three traces I've obtained but I am a bit confused when graphing these am I just suppose to pretend the k value doesn't affect my sketch at all?  I know adding a constant to equation 3 and 2 would raise the graph up/down the axis by that amount

EDIT: I've realized that a parabola is $y=a(x-h)^2+k$ and the center $(h,k)$ so I guess I can just draw it how ever I want since k is just some arbitrary constant?

Comment: The value of $k$ determines where you’re taking the slice. E.g., the intersection of the surface and the plane $x=k$ is the ellipse $(y-2)^2+\frac14(z-2)^2=k, x=k$.

Comment: @amd so I am slicing ellipses as I move up through out the yz plane? I tried graphing this stuff but All I have are two parabolas and an ellipse but I can't really connect them for the elliptic paraboloid shape that I usually see.

Comment: it's going to look like half a melon on a table (yz plane is a table), if you slice parallel to the table you'll get ellipses, but if you slice perpendicular to the table you'll get parabolas.

Comment: You’re moving along the $x$-axis, taking slices perpendicular to it, and similarly for the other coordinate axes.